# Create case from RESTlet, including attachment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How can I create a support case record from RESTlet including attachment in the email sent.

```
                var createCase = record.create({ type: record.Type.SUPPORT_CASE })
                createCase.setValue({ fieldId:'company',value:company })
                createCase.setValue({ fieldId:'customform',value:parseData.caseform })
                createCase.setValue({ fieldId:'title',value:parseData.subject })
                createCase.setValue({ fieldId:'email',value: parseData.email })
                createCase.setValue({ fieldId:'incomingmessage',value: parseData.message })
                createCase.save()
```

Using this code, a case record gets created, an email is sent by customer according to standard NetSuite functionality. but can we add an attachment to that mail? I am passing that attachment as an encoded string via postman.

I can retrieve that string in RESTlet script, but can I pass it to the mail sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by saving the attachment in the file cabinet then attaching it in an email you send via SuiteScript.

```
const fileObj  = file.load({
    id: fileId
}); 
email.send({
    author: authorId,
    recipients: customerEmail,
    subject: 'Test Email from Case',
    body: 'Test',
    attachments: [fileObj],
    relatedRecords: {
        activityId: caseId
    }
});
```

You can also choose to attach the file to the case record.

```
record.attach({
    record: {
        type: 'file',
        id: fileId
    },
    to: {
        type: 'supportcase',
        id: caseId
    }
});
```